# Issue to return int from a method

Tags: java, android

i need to return a `int` variable from a method that i show below, but with my code, method not return int variable...i don't know why!

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks in advance everybody!

```
    public int checkLogin(final String emaill, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    Log.i("ciao1", "["+response+"]");


                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite


                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
                        id= jObj.getInt("id");
                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE____ID:"+id);

                        idd= jObj.getInt("id");
                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE___ID:"+idd);


                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE ID:"+id);


                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");

                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String cognome = user.getString("cognome");

                        String emaill = user.getString("email");
                        String email2 = user.getString("email2");
                        String numero_appartamento = user.getString("numero_appartamento");
                        String nome_edificio = user.getString("nome_edificio");
                        String zona_metropolitana = user.getString("zona_metropolitana");



                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");
                        Log.i("ciao2", "[" + jObj + "]");

                        // Inserting row in users table
//                        db.addUser(name,cognome, emaill,email2,numero_appartamento,nome_edificio,zona_metropolitana,uid, created_at);
                        db.addUser(name, cognome, emaill, email2, numero_appartamento, nome_edificio, zona_metropolitana, uid, created_at);


                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
//                                MainActivity.class);
                                ScrollableTabsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", id);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }

        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", emaill);
                params.put("password", password);
                System.out.println(params);
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

        return idd;

    }
```

Comment: What does your method return then?

Comment: "method not return int variable" is extremely unclear, and I strongly suspect this isn't as short as it could be to demonstrate the problem. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: what is your idd variable initialized as?

Comment: have you tried debugging with debugger?

Comment: i have not initialized variale....only int idd;

Comment: idd take id from db correctly but return 0

Comment: @alex you question is misleading, you have to say that `my method is returning wrong value` instead of saying  `method not return int variable`  0  is an int value

Answer (score 0):

Volley requests are async, so when you try to return an int, the request is likely not done yet. If you want to return values from a Volley request use callback interfaces.

```
public void getInt(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            callback.onSuccess(<PASS INTEGER RESULT HERE>);
        }
    });
}

public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(int result);
}
```

Example usage:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getInt(new VolleyCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(int result){
             //do stuff here with the int
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: None of your method returns **int**

Comment: It is just an example to get the idea on how to return values from a async volley request, but I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

```
 public StringRequest checkLogin(final String emaill,final CallbackInterface callback, final String password) {

        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    Log.i("ciao1", "["+response+"]");


                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite


                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
                        id= jObj.getInt("id");
                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE____ID:"+id);

                        idd= jObj.getInt("id");
                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE___ID:"+idd);


                        System.out.println("BEFORE STORE THE USER IN SQLITE ID:"+id);


                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");

                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String cognome = user.getString("cognome");

                        String emaill = user.getString("email");
                        String email2 = user.getString("email2");
                        String numero_appartamento = user.getString("numero_appartamento");
                        String nome_edificio = user.getString("nome_edificio");
                        String zona_metropolitana = user.getString("zona_metropolitana");



                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");
                        Log.i("ciao2", "[" + jObj + "]");

                        // Inserting row in users table
//                        db.addUser(name,cognome, emaill,email2,numero_appartamento,nome_edificio,zona_metropolitana,uid, created_at);
                        db.addUser(name, cognome, emaill, email2, numero_appartamento, nome_edificio, zona_metropolitana, uid, created_at);


                         callback.onSuccess(idd);//implement this in your MainActivity.java    


                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }

        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", emaill);
                params.put("password", password);
                System.out.println(params);
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

        return strReq;

    }

public interface CallbackInterface {
    void onSuccess(int result);
}
```